# Summing array values by repeating index for an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I want to sum the values in `vals` into elements of a smaller array `a` specified in an index list `idx`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((1,3))
vals = np.array([1,2,3,4])
idx = np.array([0,1,2,2])

a[0,idx] += vals
```

This produces the result `[[ 1.  2.  4.]]` but I want the result `[[ 1.  2.  7.]]`, because it should add the 3 from `vals` and 4 from `vals` into the 2nd element of `a`.

I can achieve what I want with:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((1,3))
vals = np.array([1,2,3,4])
idx = np.array([0,1,2,2])

for i in np.unique(idx):
    fidx = (idx==i).astype(int)
    psum = (vals * fidx).sum()
    a[0,i] = psum 

print(a)
```

Is there a way to do this with numpy without using a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible with `np.add.at` as long as the shapes align, i.e., `a` will need to be 1D here.

```
a = a.squeeze()
np.add.at(a, idx, vals)

a
array([1., 2., 7.])
```

Comment: Or without squeezing you can just pass the specific row. `np.add.at(a[0], idx, vals)`.